# react-img-mapper doesn't work on React Typescript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using [react-img-mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-img-mapper) and
wrote code as per the doc.

but, error happens at the map and message is as below:

> Type 'Map' is not assignable to type 'import("--node_modules/react-img-mapper/dist/types").Map'.
> Types of property 'areas' are incompatible.
> Type 'MapAreas[]' is not assignable to type 'import("--node_modules/react-img-mapper/dist/types").MapAreas[]'.
> Type 'MapAreas' is missing the following properties from type 'MapAreas': active, disabled, href, strokeColor, lineWidth

what should I do to remove this error?

```
import img from './asetts/body-img.png';
import ImageMapper from 'react-img-mapper';

type MapAreas = {
    name: string;
    shape: string;
    coords:number[];
    preFillColor: string;
    fillColor: string;
  
}

type Map = {
    name: string;
    areas: Array<MapAreas>;
}

const BodyImage: React.FC = () => {

    const AREAS_MAP :Map =  { name: "mymap", areas: [
        { name: "one", shape: "circle", coords: [55,440,57], preFillColor: "green", fillColor: "blue"  },
        { name: "two", shape: "circle", coords: [185,680,117], preFillColor: "red", fillColor: "blue"  },
    ]}
    

    return (
        <div>
           <ImageMapper src={img} map={AREAS_MAP}/>  
        </div>
    )
}

export default BodyImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you import `MapAreas` , `Map` from `react-img-mapper`?

Like that:

```
import {MapAreas, Map} from 'react-img-mapper/dist/types'
```

This is an original `MapAreas` of `react-img-mapper`

```
export interface MapAreas {
    id?: string;
    shape: string;
    coords: []; // <== Problem from react-img-mapper
    active: boolean;
    disabled: boolean;
    href: string;
    fillColor: string;
    strokeColor: string;
    lineWidth: number;
    preFillColor: string;
}
```

Try you data below

```
const AREAS_MAP: MapAreas = {
    name: "mymap",
    areas: [
      {
        // name: "two",
        shape: "circle",
        // coords: [185, 680, 117],
        coords: [],
        preFillColor: "red",
        fillColor: "blue",
        active: false,
        strokeColor: "red",
        disabled: false,
        href: "href",
        lineWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  };
```